# Is there a way to "publish" ports from a container when using "fig run"?

Tags: docker, ports, fig

Sometimes when i need to debug the result of my image, i do run "/bin/bash" and do some look around on my image.

```
fig run www /bin/bash
```

From that point i can for instance, fire up a webserver myself at port 8080, but unfortunately i can't access that port from my "docker host".

Is there a way to "publish" ports from a container when using "fig run" ?

Comment: Why not expose them in fig.yml ?

Comment: They are actually "published" in fig.yml ( expose would actually just expose to linked containers, right? ).

But when you do "fig run" perhaps the "ports" from fig.yml are not "published". Running fig up www, does publish then, but doesn't let me play with /bin/bash unless i install an SSH server, which is considered "bad practice"

Comment: Ok now I see what's the problem. I don't know how to publish ports when running 'fig run', but you can always fall back to plain 'docker run'. Or you can 'fig up' and then use ns-enter (https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) to enter into your running docker container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible to publish ports when using the `run` command with the [`--service-ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli/) parameter in docker-compose.

NB! The **fig** project has changed name to **docker-compose**, and is available here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to forward ports while using fig run, as show [Fig docs page](http://www.fig.sh/rails.html):

"... One-off commands are started in new containers with the same config as a normal container for that service, so volumes, links, etc will all be created as expected. **The only thing different to a normal container is the command will be overridden with the one specified and no ports will be created in case they collide**."